# iptables rule with with random time variable argument

Tags: iptables

I am looking for long time iptables rule satisfying the following conditions.
Assuming, we have a pool of users (from: --uid owner 100, until: -- uid owner 200)
Our iptables rule:

```
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 100 -j REJECT
```

Question: How to randomly change an argument

```
--uid-owner
```

every 5 minutes?

Regards.
Mark

Comment: What is the underlying purpose of doing this? If  you are trying to limit how much network activity a given user can perform, I suspect there are other approaches that might achieve a more workable solution - having each user getting rejected traffic for 495 minutes out of every 500 minutes (`5 minutes * 100 users`) sounds like it might cause a lot of user complaints.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying purpose of doing this, is to check if iptables is capable to work with random variable argument.
Or howto build-in random variable argument into iptables rule?
[quote] to limit how much network activity a given user can perform[/quote]
This is not the point, only example.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on exactly how you wanted to do this.

The simplest way I can think of is to have a cronjob regenerate a rule every five minutes, using a random UID (how exactly you get that random UID depends on your needs, but a hack might be `--uid-owner $(( 100 + $RANDOM%100 ))`).

You would need a means of deleting the previous random rule, but that would I think otherwise match your requirements.

Another approach might be to create one rule per UID, with each looking something like:

`-A CHAIN --uid-owner NUMBER -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.9 -j DROP`

That would I think do the same as what you are suggesting - but I may have misunderstood what exaclty you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I,am afraid, I presented my position in an insufficient way.
Briefly, the idea is to REJECT entire traffic in OUTPUT chain for random user, and change the user every 5 minutes.
With other words, iptables rule:
[code]iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 100 -j REJECT[/code]
will REJECT (for one random user) entire traffic in OUTPUT chain for 5 minutes. No Internet connection.
Everyone else will enjoy Internet connection, every 5 minutes different (random) user will be discriminated

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this?

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 --uid-owner 001-100 -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.9 -j DROP